# Perl Module Manual Install Windows XP

Tags: windows, perl, windows-xp, cpan

What is the process to manually installing Perl modules on Windows XP? I've seen UNIX commands like

```
perl Makefile.PL
make
make install
```

but I can't find a comparable 'make' command in Windows commandline. I cannot use CPAN to install the modules, as firewall settings prevent the network accesses needed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://p3rl.org/CPAN#WORKING-WITH-CPAN.pm-BEHIND-FIREWALLS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Strawberry Perl includes `dmake`](http://win32.perl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Strawberry_Perl) which, to my knowledge, is essentially the same as `make` except it's built for a Windows environment.  There are also other alternatives such as [`GNU make`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm).

Comment: Ok, I see the dmake, but how exactly would I use this? I have a perl modules folder separate from my root strawberry perl folder. I know that the files have to be in that root folder, i think in site/lib correct? So do I run make file from the site/lib folder using the perl mod? Do i just copy the folder over, pms, manifest, readme and all? I haven't done much mod installing by hand before. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just untar/unzip/whatever the module, go into the top-level directory from the resulting untar/unzip/etc, and then do `perl Makefile.PL`, `dmake`, `dmake test` (optional but highly recommended), and `dmake install`.

Comment: Great, just did that. I can see the pm file and assorted others in the site/lib now. One final question, what does the dmake test do exactly? I noticed a list of ok codes. I'm assuming that if that list isn't ok, i should find a more stable release of the module?

Comment: There should be a `/t` directory that contains unit tests.  The convention is for Perl test scripts to have a `.t` extension, but they're really just Perl scripts that take advantage of one or more testing modules--usually [`Test::More`](http://search.cpan.org/~mschwern/Test-Simple-0.98/lib/Test/More.pm).  [Here](http://www.wgz.org/chromatic/perl/Test-Tutorial.pdf) are some slides that provide a simple yet useful overview of unit testing in Perl.

Comment: To answer your question:  if one or more tests fail, then you'll want to try to find out why the test failed (usually via the error message) and fix it if you can.  The reason for the test failure can be anything from a missing module that the author forgot to put in the prerequisites list to having the wrong version of a C library to an honest-to-goodness bug in either the test or the module itself (in which case, you'll want to file a bug report on CPAN to let the author(s) know).

Comment: And if you have tests failing, you *can* just say "screw it" and install the module anyways if you reeeeeeeeeally want to, but it probably won't work like it should.

Comment: Ok, well that's good to know. Thanks for the great insight! Very helpful.

Comment: You're very welcome.  If you would consider accepting the answer (by marking the check box underneath the upvote/downvote arrows next to my answer), I'd greatly appreciate it.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays Strawberry Perl includes `gmake` tool.

Trying to use `dmake` outputs `DMAKE WARNING`: `Do not use dmake.exe utility as it is no longer part of Strawberry Perl, use gmake.exe instead!`